# How to add a list to another list

Tags: python, list, function, append, extend

I have a function called "organizer" which takes 2 values a list and an index(number), to reorganize this list, after that it return a new list.

I want to execute this function 10 times to create 10 lists and add this lists to a single list of lists for later use, the program acomplish this, however it repeat the last list 10 times, it does not add the other lists.

I put the function "organizer" in here,because Im unable to find where the problem relies so more information may be needed.
I have been using the print function along the function to see where it fails, and it creates the lists as I desire, the problem is that after creating them it just copy the last created list as many times as the loop goes on. It takes the final list produced and copy it several times

Here is the code:

```
number_list = ["12","11","10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"]    
indexes = [0,5,6,8,10,4,5,2,1,9]    

def organizer(list,index): # Takes a list and reorganize it by a number which is an index.    
    number1 = index - 1    
    count_to_add = -1    
    list_to_add = []    
    for item in range(number1):    
        count_to_add += 1    
        a = list[count_to_add]    
        list_to_add.append(a)    

    number2 = index - 1    
    for item1 in range(number2):    
        del list[0]    

    list.extend(list_to_add)    
    return list    


def lists_creator(list_indexes):  # Create a list of 10 lists ,with 12 elements each.    
    final_list = []
    count = -1

    for item in list_indexes:
        count += 1
        result = organizer(number_list, list_indexes[count])
        final_list.append(result)

    return final_list

final_output = lists_creator(indexes)
print(final_output)
```

Here is the result:(the same list 10 times)

```
[['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8']]
```

Note: If I change the line 28 in list_creator function

```
final_list.append(result)
```

for

```
final_list.extend(result)
```

the result is:

```
['12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8']
```

Which is the result that I desire but is not a group of lists.

Comment: It'll be easier to follow if you avoid mutating the input list, but instead copy it and mutate the copy. So in the first line of `organizer()`, do `list = list.copy()`.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but avoid using python keywords such as `list` as variable names. Call it `myList` instead for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the same list every time, so the result consists of actually one list,

in your `list_creator` method, you have to give to `organizer` method a copy of your original list `number_list`, otherwise you just mutate over and over again the same one list:

```
def lists_creator(list_indexes):  # Create a list of 10 lists ,with 12 elements each.    
    final_list = []
    count = -1

    for item in list_indexes:
        count += 1
        result = organizer(list(number_list), list_indexes[count])
        final_list.append(result)

    return final_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lists_creator(list_indexes):  # Create a list of 10 lists ,with 12 elements each.
    final_list = []
    list = []

    for i in range(len(list_indexes)):
        result = organizer(number_list, list_indexes[i])
        list.extend(result)

    n = 0
    m = 12
    for n_times in range(len(list_indexes)):
        final_list.append(list[n:m])
        n = m
        m += 12

    return final_list
```